# how to fulfill two conditions inside a defined function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there is a way to fulfill two if statements simultaneously. I have the following code:

```
def crossingTime(self, level, channel_data, times):                         
    ndata = len(channel_data)                                               
    for i in range(ndata-1):                                                
        thisADC = channel_data[i]                                           
        nextADC = channel_data[i+1]                                         
        if thisADC >= level and nextADC < level:                            
            return times[i]
```

The code is fully functional, but I want to implement a second condition, which should be fulfilled simultaneously after if statement:

```
if thisADC <= level and nextADC > level:
   return times[i]
```

However, I'm not completely sure how to go about that. Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your question, if you just want another condition just add those 2 lines after the existing condition and make sure the `if` is indented to the right level (same as the other `if`).

Comment: how can `nextADC < level` and `nextADC > level` happen at the same time?

Comment: I have a signal that basically looks like a pulse, so this should tell me when the signal fall below level, but I also need to find when the signal went up to level after reaching the minimum.

Comment: @Exprator No he is right. `thisADC` and `nextADC` is ofcourse different. But what OP asks in the question looks like he wants something like `nextADC < level:` in one line and below he wants to check `nextADC > level` which is definitely not possible and absurd.

Comment: @RamiroTorres your question is confusing what exactly do you want

Comment: I am using this function to know when a pmt pulse signal falls below a certain level and how long does it take for it to reach the level again.

Comment: Did you try the solution of my answer?

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you mean by "fulfill".

Comment: What I mean by fulfill is to satisfy both conditions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return `times[i]` if **either** of your conditions is true, why not just doing:

```
if thisADC >= level and nextADC < level or thisADC <= level and nextADC > level:
    return times[i]
```